# Comparing every fourth line of two gzipped files

Tags: python, gzip

I have 2 gzipped files of about 1Gb each. I want to read in both files  simultaneously and compare every fourth line of both files with each other. Is there a faster way then doing it like this?

```
import gzip

file1 = r"path\to\file1.gz"
file2 = r"path\to\file2.gz"


for idx, (line1, line2) in enumerate(zip(gzip.open(file1), gzip.open(file2)), start=1):
    if not idx%4:
        compare(line1, line2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still have to iterate through both files, but this is cleaner:

```
import gzip
from itertools import islice, izip

file1 = r"path\to\file1.gz"
file2 = r"path\to\file2.gz"

with gzip.open(file1) as f1, gzip.open(file2) as f2:
    for line1, line2 in islice(izip(f1, f2)), 3, None, 4):
        compare(line1, line2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.islice(iterable, 3, None, 4)` to iterate over every fourth item in `iterable`.

If you are on Python 2.x, use `itertools.izip` instead of `zip` to avoid reading everything in memory.